# How to import data from a .sql file which has gzipped content on windows

Tags: gzip, mysql

I have used the below command to compress and backup my data in a Linux server.
mysqldump -u root --triggers --routines --all-databases | gzip > MyDBs.sql

Now i would like to have all these data restored in my local machine which is a windows 7 machine. When i tried importing the same in MySQL GUI tools, it gives error.
Can anyone please tel me how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your file is not really an sql file, it's a gzip with the wrong file extension. rename the file Extension from .sql to .gzip, unzip it and Import the unzipped .sql file in it to your Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from the comments, please accept

> Your file is not really an sql file, it's a gzip with the wrong file
>   extension. rename the file Extension from .sql to .gzip, unzip it and
>   Import the unzipped .sql file in it to your Server.